# Infinitely poll data base and emit results nonblocking

Tags: java, database, spring, nonblocking, reactive

**Problem statement**: observe and publish (external) changes (by last update timestamp) beginning after a given timestamp (from) of a Oracle data base with Spring Reactive stack.

**What I had in mind:**

1. create Flux
2. create a data base cursor (select * from foo where f.timestamp > from)
3. start on subscription (cold observable)
   end when cursor has not more values
4. wait a given time
5. repeat all steps *after* last timestamp from the latest emitted value

**Where I fail:** I know how to create a Flux periodically emitting values with *Flux.interval* and how to generate a state aware (state = timestamp) Flux with *Flux.generate* but not how to combine them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `delayElements` and combine it with your existing stateful generate.

```
Flux.generate(sink -> sink.next(new Date()))
    .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(5000));
```

The delay controls the execution frequency the gernerate function, so subscribing to and logging this would produce:

```
Tue Apr 24 16:24:41 BST 2018
Tue Apr 24 16:24:46 BST 2018
Tue Apr 24 16:24:51 BST 2018
Tue Apr 24 16:24:56 BST 2018
Tue Apr 24 16:25:01 BST 2018
...
```

This is designed to replace the zip with Interval pattern. For further information see the [javadoc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#delayElements-java.time.Duration-).

Comment: I moved on to another programming problem, I will try out your solution when I am back.